# Keep GridViewRow width within GridView bound

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am trying to keep a GridView row with in GridView bounds

 so that if some one resize the column the whole size of row remains with in GridView 
**no scrollbar**.!

[Correct Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7XPD.png)

But anyone can resize the column like that!

[Wrong Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0aTL.png)

You may see that the wrong behaviour screenshot has scrollbar, i do not want this expand the column with in grid bounds.

I am attaching part of code

```
<Grid >

        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
      <RowDefinition Height="255" />
         ......
      <RowDefinition  />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<!-->msv is Custom ListView to allow multi select<--!>
      <msv:MultiSelectListView  x:Name="listView"   
      Grid.Row="0"   
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContStyle}" SelectionMode="Extended">

            <msv:MultiSelectListView.View >
               <GridView >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="File Name"  Width="360" fwc:GridViewSort.PropertyName="FileName">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <Label Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Content="{Binding FileName}" ToolTip="{Binding FileName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
                </msv:MultiSelectListView.View>
            </msv:MultiSelectListView>

</grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a simple way to do this.  Please see this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/84529/Simulate-WPF-ListView-Column-Width-Set-to) for an example of having a '*' sized GridViewColumn, which is what I think you need.